# How to see all processes running on Docker Daemon VM on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-daemon

I'd like to know what processes run in VM with Docker Daemon on a Windows 10 host.

How could I connect to the VM and list those processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean to a remote Docker Daemon? You can use [Docker Contexts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/) to be able to run all of the standard Docker commands remotely.

Once you have a context setup for the VM Docker Daemon, you can do for example:

`docker ps`, `docker top` and so on, like this:

`docker --context <VM's context name> top`

If you just mean connect to the daemon locally, you can [SSH into the daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370059/connect-with-ssh-to-docker-daemon-on-windows), and [run the usual Linux commands](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-all-running-processes-in-linux/).