# Where are the Docker Desktop for Windows kubelet logs located?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I can't find where the kubelet logs are located for Docker Desktop (Windows). There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34113476/where-are-the-kubernetes-kubelet-logs-located), but the answers all refer to linux/kind installs of kubernetes.

Comment: Where are you running this? Mac or Windows?

Comment: Just realized that it's _also_ called Docker Desktop on Mac. Edited the title.

Answer (score 2):

To get `kubelet` logs you need to get access to the virtual machine that docker daemon runs in. Since there is no `ssh` available there is workaround for this:

Here`s how to login into VM:

```
docker run --privileged -it -v /:/host -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jongallant/ubuntu-docker-client
```

and then use this command to get the kubelet logs:

```
ls /host/var/log/kubelet*
```

Please note that this is just workaround for tool that was designed for testing and it`s not the official supported way.  This case also describes how to [ssh to docker deamon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370059/connect-with-ssh-to-docker-daemon-on-windows).

Answer (score 2):

*I get that this is an old question, but it does seem to get some traffic, has no accepted answer and is the only of this kind on SO - here is my take on this problem and a solution:*

### The process

As already pointed out by @acid_fuji, everything is running inside a VM we need to access, to get the required information. As most things in Linux have some representation in the filesystem, and tools like `ps` use *procfs* to query the requested information, mounting the VMs root directory (`/`) ist sufficient for introspection and quite easy:

Run a container and mount the VMs root directory `/` to `/host`:

```bash
docker run --rm -it -v /:/host alpine
```

In that container, get a shell with the VMs root directory in `/host` as root `/`:

```bash
chroot /host
```

From this shell with changed root directory, tools like `ps` will return information about the VM and not your container anymore. Next step is to find some information about the running `kubelet`. Get a tree formatted list of all running processes in the VM with their command line and highlight *kubelet*:

```bash
ps -ef --forest | grep --color -E 'kubelet|$'
```

Reduced to the relevant portions, the result will look something like this:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
...
root        30     1  0 Aug11 ?        00:05:09 /usr/bin/memlogd -fd-log 3 -fd-query 4 -max-lines 5000 -max-line-len 1024
...
root       543     1  0 Aug11 ?        00:00:16 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace services.linuxkit -id docker -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock
root       563   543  0 Aug11 ?        00:00:02  \_ /usr/bin/docker-init /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
root       580   563  0 Aug11 ?        00:00:00  |   \_ /bin/sh /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
root       679   580  0 Aug11 ?        00:00:00  |       \_ /usr/bin/logwrite -n lifecycle-server /usr/bin/lifecycle-server
root       683   679  0 Aug11 ?        00:00:35  |           \_ /usr/bin/lifecycle-server
...
root      1539   683  0 Aug11 ?        00:00:01  |               \_ /usr/bin/logwrite -n kubelet kubelet --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config /etc/kubeadm/kubelet.yaml --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --hostname-override=docker-desktop --container-runtime=remote --container-runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
root      1544  1539  2 Aug11 ?        00:38:38  |                   \_ kubelet --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config /etc/kubeadm/kubelet.yaml --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --hostname-override=docker-desktop --container-runtime=remote --container-runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
```

We find `kubelet` as PID **1544**, spawned by `logwrite` (PID **1539**). Issuing `logwrite --help` we find the `-n` flag to set the name to appear in logs for the launched instance, and `logwrite` to be sending its logs to `memlogd`, which we find as PID **30**.

Knowing what to search for I found this blog post [Capturing Logs in Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/blog/capturing-logs-in-docker-desktop/) describing how logging in *Docker Desktop* is implemented. What we can learn:

`logwrite` and `memlogd` are part of [Linuxkit](https://github.com/linuxkit/linuxkit), and LinuxKit provides binaries of their packages as containers, with the logging infrastructure as [`linuxkit/memlogd`](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxkit/memlogd). `memlogd` has a socket to query for logs at `/run/guest-services/memlogdq.sock`.

*Be aware, that the `latest`-tag on `linuxkit/memlogd` is quite useless and pick a specific tag matching the running version in the VM; just try another version if the next step errors.*

### The solution

Run `logread` from [`linuxkit/memlogd`](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxkit/memlogd) and mount the VMs `/run/guest-services/memlogdq.sock` to the `logread`s expected default location at `/var/run/memlogdq.sock`. Tell `logread` to either show only new entries and follow, using `-f`, or dump all existing entries and follow with `-F`. Pipe this through something like grep, or a powershell equivalent and filter for `kubelet`:

```bash
# example assuming presence grep on windows
docker run --rm -it -v /run/guest-services/memlogdq.sock:/var/run/memlogdq.sock linuxkit/memlogd:014f86dce2ea4bb2ec13e92ae5c1e854bcefec40 /usr/bin/logread -F | grep -i kubelet
```

Tag `014f86dce2ea4bb2ec13e92ae5c1e854bcefec40` is working with *Docker Desktop `v4.11.1`*; just test which container version/tag works with your docker version.