# How to access system level logs when using Kubernetes support for Docker Desktop with WSL 2?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am beyond confused about what is actually happening on my computer when using Docker Desktop + the WSL 2 based engine + Kubernetes support for Docker Desktop. I have the following environment setup on my Windows 10 machine:

- Docker Desktop for Windows 10
- I enabled the WSL 2 based engine
- I enabled Kubernetes support

So where exactly would logs from the various Kubernetes and Docker components be going? [The Kubernetes Logging Architecture documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#system-component-logs) explains that there are two kinds of system components - components that run in containers such as the Kubernetes Scheduler and kube-proxy and those that do not run in containers such as the kubelet and the container runtime. Given the above configuration (Docker Desktop + WSL 2) how would I access the kubelet and container runtime logs? The documentation states:

```
On machines with systemd, the kubelet and container runtime write to journald. If systemd is not present, they write to .log files in the /var/log directory. System components inside containers always write to the /var/log directory, bypassing the default logging mechanism.
```

How exactly can I view these logs from a shell? I have tried using a Ubuntu shell and browsing around but I don't see any obvious log files:
[image]

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711842/) ?

Comment: I did not see that. Thanks for providing the link!